# clipsToBounds seeming to have no effect in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Is it possible to have a subview render outside a `UIStackView`? I have a vertical stack view with a button and a label, and I'm using the width of the stack view to set the button's height and width appropriately:

```
addArrangedSubview(self.loginMethodButton)
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.loginMethodButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.loginMethodButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.loginMethodButton, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

I then adjust the width in my viewController to appropriate sizes based on the situation. The problem is, in one of the smaller sizes the button needs to be, the width is smaller than the label beneath it, which cuts off the label.

[image]

If I call `sizeToFit()` when setting the label, it works, however, calling `sizeToFit()` when adjusting the sizes after the label has been set still results in the label being cut off. Setting `clipsToBounds` to false on both the label and stack view have no effect.

Is it possible to render a view outside of a stack view at all? Or am I going to have to find a way to re-work my constraints in order to fix this issue?

Comment: check if you have another view in the hierarchy maybe that is the problem, also check for the UILabel breakLineMode it seems for me that is truncateTail instead of wordBreak

Comment: It needs to fit on a single line, the text is simply saying `Touch ID` or `Passcode` so line breaks wouldn't be acceptable. As far as view hierarchy, it's all created programmatically in a subclass of `UIStackView`, my `setUpView` method only ever adds two arranged views, the label and the button, so there shouldn't be any extra views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIStackView` is a "non-rendering" object... all it does is arrange other views.

If the problem is that your `UILabel` is too wide to fit in the area made available by your Stack View, then you either need to set the label to "auto-shrink" the font, or you need to alter your Stack View constraints to allow for the wider label.

**Edit** *Based on your other comment, the following was incorrect.*

You need to set `.clipsToBounds` on the "containing" view... based on the graphic you are showing, that would be the darker-blue box (I'm assuming that is a `UIView` with the image and label as subviews).

Comment: Shoot.... That blue box is just the background it's on. This vertical stackView is being arranged inside of a horizontal stack view, which is being layoued on the screen, so the "containing" view would reach all the way up to my main view controller's view, setting `clipsToBounds` there doesn't have an effect. Edit: Shoot, I'm trying to figure out a good way to alter my constraints now.

Comment: If it's "non-rendering" object why it's has background color?

Comment: @Ahmadreza - this is an old answer... while it still solves the OP's issue, `UIStackView` has changed with `iOS 14` (after this answer was posted).  See this article for an explanation: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stack-view-background-color-in-ios-14/