# View will move out of parent bounds when doing transition animation

Tags: ios

Here is the code to reproduce this problem. You can  paste it to Playground to execute

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import AVKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let root = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
root.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let container = UIStackView()
container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
container.axis = .vertical
container.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
root.addSubview(container)
container.distribution = .fill

let colors = [UIColor.yellow, .green]
for i in 0..<4 {
    let child = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)))
    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    child.backgroundColor = colors[i%colors.count]
    if i == 0 || i == 3 {
        child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    } else {
        child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
    child.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    child.text = String(i)
    container.addArrangedSubview(child)
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = root
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.transition(with: container, duration: 3, options: [.showHideTransitionViews], animations: {
            container.subviews[2].isHidden = true
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

### Question

[image]

The view which is going to hide will always goes out of parent bounds. I have tried to set `clipToBounds` to parent, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `UIStackView` won't clip sub view. So wrap a `UIView` to it and set `clipToBounds=true` will solve this problem.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334551/clipstobounds-seeming-to-have-no-effect-in-uistackview)