# Swift: Unable to clip image in stackView

Tags: swift

I am attempting to layout an `imageView` inside a `stackView` and was unable to clip the image. The layout was correctly done when no image was inserted as shown:

[image]

However, when I insert a dummy image (a portrait image) to test the `contentMode` and `clipsToBounds`, it stretched, like so:

[image]

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334551/clipstobounds-seeming-to-have-no-effect-in-uistackview) and also tried to layout the `imageView` inside a `UIView` before stacking inside the stackView but it still gave the same result. Note that I would want my two labels to adopt its `intrinsicContentSize` as the `titleLabel` may take up 1 or 2 lines. I would want the imageView to adjust accordingly.

My implementation:

```
   let drawingPreviewImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
        iv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            drawingPreviewImageView,
            numberLabel,
            titleLabel,
            ])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 4
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4 )

        addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
            ])
```

Any advice?

Comment: Add constraints to the imageView to restrict its size. I cannot see any constraints applied to the imageView

Comment: @Scriptable that would work, but I want the two labels to adopt the intrinsicContentSize. The title could take up 1-2 lines, so I want the imageView to adjust accordingly.

Comment: "but I want the two labels to adopt the intrinsicContentSize" But you are also allowing the _image view_ to adopt its intrinsic content size. That means that it just grows to fit the image.

Comment: @matt sounds like this use case isn't suitable to be used in a stackView? That I have to lay them out manually?

Comment: Well, I didn't say that, but you are not doing evenly spaced distribution or anything, so it's hard to see what the stack view is for. Still, you'll have the same issue without the stack view: an image view under autolayout grows to fit its image unless you add height / width constraints.

Comment: I think that you should start by making hugging and compression resistance priorities for your labels and image view.

Comment: @Sulthan Don't quite understand, mind showing some code?